# Detect ctrl+s and reload browser

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation

I have two monitors.

One with Visual Studio. And the other with the Browser showing the result of my code.

I repeatedly do `this crazy thing`:

- code something in visual studio.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in visual studio.
- Then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to the browser.
- Then <kbd>f5</kbd> in the browser.
- Then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to return to Visual Studio.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Maybe some (master)code-control in Visual Studio to reload the browser every time I do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try design view https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94INFMu9ZbM

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Web Essentials 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) extension, it has such feature. Actually it can even works in both directions - if you change something using browser's developer tools, the change is saved into source files in Visual Studio ([Browser Link](http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink) feature).

It has much more handy features for a web development, so it's definitely worth trying.